# BASH - how can i take the IP address and make like expected list?

Tags: bash, awk

How to search from a file those lines and take the last IP address only:

```
2014-02-14 06:42:00.527219 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [100@xxxxxx] from 172.246.198.82
2014-02-14 06:50:44.967314 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [500@xxxxxx] from 172.246.162.250
2014-02-14 06:54:38.587312 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [100@xxxxxx] from 172.246.198.82
2014-02-14 07:05:32.667277 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [100@xxxxxx] from 172.246.198.82
2014-02-14 07:10:08.067256 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [100@xxxxxx] from 188.138.118.22
2014-02-14 07:16:29.747256 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [100@xxxxxx] from 172.246.198.82
2014-02-14 07:30:16.587253 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [100@xxxxxx] from 188.138.118.22
2014-02-14 07:46:10.727254 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [admin@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 07:46:11.247254 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [admin@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 07:46:11.767254 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [admin@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 07:46:12.267221 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [admin@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 07:46:12.767224 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [admin@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 07:46:13.307251 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [admin@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 07:46:13.767254 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [admin@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 07:46:14.587252 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [admin@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 07:46:15.267221 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [admin@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 07:46:16.007254 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [admin@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 07:46:16.507251 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [admin@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 07:46:20.347236 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [admin@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 07:46:20.807254 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [admin@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 08:01:18.467226 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [100@xxxxxx] from 188.138.118.22
2014-02-14 08:32:18.127200 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [100@xxxxxx] from 188.138.118.22
2014-02-14 09:00:29.967234 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [3000@xxxxxx] from 172.246.162.250
2014-02-14 09:03:13.207173 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [100@xxxxxx] from 188.138.118.22
2014-02-14 09:07:35.747256 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [6000@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 09:07:36.187216 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [6000@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 09:07:36.627217 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [6000@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 09:07:37.067262 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [6000@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 09:07:37.507219 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [6000@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 09:07:37.927256 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [6000@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 09:07:38.307205 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [6000@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 09:07:38.947256 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [6000@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 09:07:39.587246 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [6000@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 09:07:40.327255 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [6000@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 09:07:40.767255 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [6000@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 09:07:41.207189 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [6000@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 09:07:41.667163 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [6000@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 09:07:42.107255 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [6000@xxxxxx] from 207.244.67.213
2014-02-14 09:14:53.367170 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [3000@xxxxxx] from 172.246.162.250
2014-02-14 09:18:57.127288 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2701 Can't find user [340136@xxxxxx] from 199.115.112.66
```

to make a list from above to following:

```
-A INPUT -s 176.58.71.212/32 -j DROP
..
```

tried: but not working like expected

```
grep "Can't find user" /usr/local/freeswitch/log/freeswitch.log | awk '{print $10}' | xargs echo "-A \n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is as follows :-

```
grep "Can't find user" /usr/local/freeswitch/log/freeswitch.log | \
awk  '{print "-A INPUT -s " $10 "-j DROP"}'
```

As requested in the comments you would like to remove the duplicates. This can be achieved as follows :-

```
grep "Can't find user" /usr/local/freeswitch/log/freeswitch.log | \
awk  '{print "-A INPUT -s " $10 "-j DROP"}' | sort -u
```

As noted in the comments there are other ways to do this that are slightly longer to explain but also probably slightly quicker to execute. awk can match the pattern itself meaning we do not need the grep. This could be done as follows :-

```
awk  '/find user/ {print "-A INPUT -s " $NF "-j DROP"}' /usr/local/freeswitch/log/freeswitch.log
```

*N.B. I have used the string "find user" rather than "Can't find user" to avoid string escaping issues.*

You could also use awk variable $NF (Number of fields) to make your script a little more robust.

Comment: +1 but I would rather use `$NF` than `$10` just to be safe. You can also use `awk '/Can’t find user/ { . . . }’ /usr/local/freeswitch/log/freeswitch.log` instead of using `grep`.

Comment: Instead of piping `grep` output to `awk`, would rather use awk to filter text.

Comment: @Steve Weet: `grep "Can't find user" /usr/local/freeswitch/log/freeswitch.log | 
awk  '{print "-A INPUT -s " $10 "-j DROP"}' ` But it list all duplicates too is there any way to remove the duplicates and take one only?

Comment: `tac /tmp/file | sort -r -u` but instead of /tmp/file can it be in the same one line?

Comment: @YumYumYum Just change it to `{if(a[$NF]++==0)print "-A INPUT -s " $NF "-j DROP"}`

Comment: OK - `grep "Can't find user" /usr/local/freeswitch/log/freeswitch.log | awk  '{print "-A INPUT -s " $10 "-j DROP"}' > /tmp/file; tac /tmp/file | sort -r -u`

Answer (score 1):

Try this to avoid dups

```
awk '/Can'"'"'t find user/ && !x[$NF]++ { print "-A INPUT -s " $NF "-j DROP" }' /usr/local/freeswitch/log/freeswitch.log
```

Comment: SO highlighting gives an error away here. I think you need to escape the single quote in can't somehow, or double quote it and escape both of the `$NF`

Comment: If using bash you probably need to escape the ! as well. This will get interpreted as a bash history event.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @SteveWeet. Since it is inside `awk`, `!` won’t complain. It is an `awk` idiom explained [here](http://backreference.org/2011/11/17/remove-duplicates-but-keeping-only-the-last-occurrence/).

Comment: Does for me ` awk '/Can\'t find user/ && !x[$NF]++ { print "-A INPUT -s " $NF "-j DROP" }' /tmp/xx
-bash: !x[$NF]++: event not found
`

Comment: @SteveWeet I added a small test for you.

Comment: @jaypalsingh Try `shopt -s histappend` and then re-try the test.

Comment: It's something to do with the quoting of the apostrophe. Your test worked but I changed the command to `awk '/jaypal\'s/ && !x[$0]++ { print $0 }' tmp` and it failed with bash: !x[$0]++: event not found

Comment: Well done @BroSlow I had just come to the conclusion it must be a bash option.

Comment: Or do `awk '/jaypal'"'"'s/ && !x[$NF]++ { print $0 }’ tmp`. I forgot single quotes cannot be used inside single quotes. :)